# Adding git to PATH for awsebcli

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, path, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using the `awsebcli` to create an elastic beanstalk instance on terminal

In order to get terminal to recognize the `eb` command, I had to configure my `~/.bash_profile` to this:

```
# Setting the path for Python 3.8
PATH="/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/bin"
export PATH
```

After running `source ~/.bash_profile` terminal started recognizing the `eb` command.

However, during the `eb init` set up flow I get this error:

```
ERROR: CommandError - Your project is using git, but git doesn't appear to be installed.
Have you added git to your PATH?
```

I then noticed the `git` cli was no longer being recognized. I got it to work again by emptying out my `~./bash_profile` file and running `source ~/.bash_profile` again

So now I am in this limbo where `eb` doesn't work without the `PATH` specified in my `~./bash_profile` but then I can't finish the setup without git. I know the solution involves some sort of edit to the `PATH` but I'm not sure what that needs to be.

Comment: What is the meaning of _emptying out_????

Comment: @user1934428 removing all text from the file

Comment: If you make the file empty, and **then** `source` it into your current bash shell, it can't have any effect to your shell. Sourcing an empty file does not change anything. Creating a new login shell from fresh would make a difference, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
# Setting the path for Python 3.8
PATH="$PATH:/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/bin"
export PATH
```

so you don't overwrite the `PATH` but add to it.